# Ajax search box displays nothing if taxonomy doesn't exist

Tags: php, javascript

Hi i have a ajax search box that pulls all my taxonomies from my post type but if I start typing and the taxonomy does not exist it just displays a small box with nothing in it. is it possible to change this so if the taxonomy does not exist it pops up in the box saying 'no search results found'

this is my function:

```
function fetch(){
    var keyword = jQuery('#listing_tags').val();

    var myDiv = document.getElementById("ajaxbox");

    if (keyword != "")
    {
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
    }

    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',{'action':'my_action','keyword': keyword},
    function(response){
    jQuery('#datafetch').html('');
    jQuery('#datafetch').append(response);
});
}
jQuery(document).on('click','#datafetch li',function(){
var val = jQuery(this).html();
jQuery('#listing_tags').val(val);
jQuery('#datafetch').html('');

var myDiv = document.getElementById("ajaxbox");
myDiv.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the response. I don't know what your php function returns but I assume it returns nothing while not found. Lets modify the `fetch()` function to check whether response is empty or not. From the code bellow you will get the idea of where to implement the popup.

```
function fetch() {
    var keyword = jQuery('#listing_tags').val();
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("ajaxbox");
    if (keyword != "") {
        myDiv.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        myDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
    jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url('
        admin - ajax.php '); ?>', {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'keyword': keyword
        },
        function(response) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html('');
            if(response.trim()==''){
                //This code will run when response is empty
                jQuery('#datafetch').append('<p>no search results found</p>');
            }else{
                //This code will run if there is valid response
                jQuery('#datafetch').append(response);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: sorry i noticed this is the same and you changed the response function but when i add your code it still shows the blank box

Comment: Hi, I assumed the ajax callback is null. Anyway I've updated my answer. Can you check back? It will be best if you can paste the ajax callback function too.

Comment: hi, still nothing the address is https://www.woohwho.com

Comment: @JoeCold Try now. This time it should work. If not then you might change the callback function to return something relevant to empty.